# Strange behaviour on if into a for

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
for($nrt=0; $nrt<$actualline; $nrt++) {
    echo $sidesIndexes[$nrt]." - ".$nrt."<br/>";
    if($sidesIndexes[$nrt]==$nrt) {
        echo "am I in??? ".$sidesIndexes[$nrt]." is different than ".$nrt."<br/>";
    }
}
```

that print :

```
# - 0
am I in??? # is different than 0
# - 1
# - 2
# - 3
# - 4
# - 5
# - 6
# - 7
# - 8
# - 9
# - 10
# - 11
# - 12
# - 13
# - 14
# - 15
# - 16
# - 17
# - 18
# - 19
```

am I tired? How is possible to get that `am I in??? # is different than 0` message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing the comparison, [the **"#"** string is converted to a numeric value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which gives **0**.

Then yes, 0 == 0.

You should use **===** to compare with checking the variable types :

```
if($sidesIndexes[$nrt] === $nrt) {
```

This will only be true if the two variable are both the same type (like integers, strings, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

In php '#' == 0 resolves to true

Learn more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @Daniel A. White `var_dump((integer) '#')` is `int(0)`. PHP tries to evaluate a comparison operation by converting the values into a common type. In this case, integer. Since (string) # converts to (integer) 0 this operation results in true.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is PHP since it looks like it. Zero evaluates to a number of things in PHP. In this case it looks like 0 == null. To have a strong equality comparison where the types are also checked, use ===.

```
0 == null // true
0 == false // true
0 == 0 // true

0 === null // false
0 === false // false
0 === 0 // true
```

Comment: Got it. Then 0 == 0 is still going to be true. The triple equals will still work for you if you dont want '#' == 0 to be true.

Comment: No it won't, but it means that `'#' === 0` is not true. Using `===` doesn't magically change what `==` means.

Comment: @Tomalak, that is what I said: '#' === 0 // false while '#' == 0 // true

Answer (score 1):

In PHP (and other loose-typed languages such as Javascript), there is a major issue when comparing two variables of different type using the double-equal operator `==`.

The two variables are different types, but PHP can only compare entities that are the same type, so when it sees the attempt to compare, it automatically converts the entities so that they are of the same type.

The result of this is that if you compare a string value `"#"` with numeric zero, it will convert the string into a numeric prior to doing the comparison. Since this results in a numeric of zero value, it equals the numeric zero it is comparing with, resulting in the `if()` condition returning true.

In some cases, this is actually the desired effect -- for instance, all data that comes into PHP from the browser in `$_POST` etc will be strings, even though it may actually be numerical data.

However in many cases, the implicit type conversion of double-equal is a major problem.

The solution to this is the tripple-equal operator - `===`.

This works exactly like the double-equal operator, except that it doesn't perform a type conversion first. If the types are not the same, then it always returns false.

Therefore, if you have a tripple-equal, a string containing the digit `"2"` would not equal an integer value of 2, and neither of them would equal a floating point value of 2.00. But with double-equal, they *would* all be equal.

In your case, you need to use the tripple-equal operator. Both have their uses, and you should use whichever one is appropriate to any given situation.

Answer (score 0):

0 is the same as false in PHP. The character '#' is not true in PHP. So, you're asking if false == false, which it does.

Comment: I think the string "#" is being converted to a numerical value (which gives 0) instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If you try a type depending compare then you should use the === operator
if($sidesIndexes[$nrt] === $nrt) {
....
}

plural of Index is Indices
side? do you mean site?